# need help in following assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86

This is simple question but I am new in assembly language. Can anyone please answer them? Thanks.

```
A BYTE 0Ah,20,10,40

B WORD 30,40,50,0Bh

D DWORD A00,200,300,400,500,600
```

a)  What is the one line command to move `A[2]` in to the eax register

b)  What is `[A+2]`?

c)  What is `[B+2]`?

d)  What is `[D+4]`?

e)  What is `[D-10]`?

Answers:

```
a)  mov eax, A[2]

b)  [A+2] is third array position that is 10.

c)  [B+2] is zero

d)  [D+4] is 200

e)  [D-10] is byte 40
```

Comment: which is the question? you have the answers already in there

Comment: The answers for A, C and E look incorrect to me. Please explain your reasoning.

Comment: first part is question i am doubt about my answer.Are they correct?

Comment: A. mov will move A[2] into wax register.

Comment: No. `A` is an array of bytes, and `EAX` is 4 bytes, so it would move the `DWORD` starting with `A[2]` into `EAX`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**a)** `A[2]` is nothing but a byte of information, and as such, you should move it into a byte-long register. You could move it into the *lower byte* of the `EAX` register, writing `MOV AL, [A+2]`.(*)
Check the `EAX` register configuration [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_register#32-bit).
So, what will your code do instead? Well, it is meant to move the 4 bytes starting from `[A+2]` in the `EAX` register, because 4 bytes is the size of `EAX`.

**c)** It depends on the [Endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your memory. In the majority of PCs, your answer would be wrong since the data is stored as `30 00, 40 00, ....` that is, the most significant bit is at the right (this way of storing data is what is referred to as the `little-endian` way), but you would be right if your CPU architecture does implement the big-endian way.

**e)** If you declare the data segment in the exact way you posted, then you would have `[D-10] = [A+2] = 10`. The reason is, datas in `B` fill 8 byte of memory, `[A+3]` is the ninth and `[A+2]` the tenth byte, going backwards.

**(*)** Please note that, as Michael reports in the comments below, you can use the `movsx` or `movzx` instructions.

`MOVSX EAX, [A+2]` will move `[A+2]` byte to `EAX` doubleword, extending the sign of the number.

`MOVZX EAX, [A+2]` will move `[A+2]` byte to `EAX` doubleword, placing all 0s in the remaining 24 bits.

The other answers seem correct to me.

Comment: a) starting with the 80386 there's `movsx` and `movzx`.